# very simple java cms

Tags: java, content-management-system

can any one suggest me a very very simple java cms.I have seen cms like opencms but they are very dificult to understand.
I want a light weighted cms with very minimum features

Comment: You could also take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419968/best-open-source-java-cms

Comment: very simple to install and use or very simple to customize?

Comment: both. simple to use,install and customize

Comment: There is nothing simple about a CMS. Maybe all you want is a repository.

Answer (score 1):

ZCMS is your Answer. It´s a simple and lightning-fast Java CMS less than 2Mb.

http://code.google.com/p/zencherry-cms/downloads/list

Also have a look on [Liferay](http://www.liferay.com/). Basically its a portal but a very good for CMS also.

Comment: fast or not, ZCMS is really insecure and not very well put together

Comment: No kidding. Just looked at the source and first thing I see is the easiest SQL injection hole I have ever seen.

Comment: I take a look at ZCMS code. Terrible. Never, never, never.

Answer (score 0):

Check [List of content management systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_content_management_systems#Java)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at JeaseCMS. It's very easy to install, to use and to customize:

http://www.jease.org/

Comment: Has anybody used in real life? Is easy extendible? Based on ZK ... framework category "hate or love". One database dead, the second with not friendly licence ... You can convince me?